# Bug in input type='reset' in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, forms, internet-explorer

I get a strange error when I use input type='reset' in internet explorer.

I have this form for searching. I pass it though jQuery to get my output and it works. Except when I use reset. Then it returns nothing.
JQUERY

```
function findExercise(idSearch) {

    $("#"+idSearch).submit(function() {

        var find = $(this).serialize();
        var php_file = "search.php?"+find
        alert(php_file);
        $("#ajax_output").load(php_file);

        return false;
    });

}
```

FORM

```
<form id='search'>
    <input value='' name='input1'>

    <select style='width:140px;' name='input2'>
        <option>option1</option>
        <option>option2</option>
        <option>option3</option>

    </select>
    <br />
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Search"><input id="resetform" type="reset" class="button" value="Clear">
```

Before I click reset it returns

> search.php?input1=b&input2=option1

After I click reset it returns

> search.php?input1=

This ONLY happens in IE.

Comment: that might be a bug with jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Seems that it was my select that was causing the error. It didnt have a default value, so when IE reset it, it took it out of the loop. I just added the following selected and it worked :D

```
<select style='width:140px;' name='input2'>
    <option selected="selected">option1</option>
    <option>option2</option>
    <option>option3</option>

</select>
```